# Web based script to determine system information

Tags: web-applications, scripting, system, information-retrieval

I know web based scripts can be used to identify the charactertics of vistors (display resolution, Java version, OS, architecture, render engine, etc)

But is there anything that could give me amount of system memory resident on the vistors PC?

Comment: I hope not! Why would you need to know the amount of memory of a client PC visiting your web site?

Comment: And why do you want to know how much memory do your users have?

Comment: 90% curiosity
10% I work for Microsoft and we’re working on Microsoft ME II SP7 and there are some features we need to extract

Answer (score 0):

Using JavaScript and the properties the browser gives you, then no. If you manage to run an ActiveX you may be able to, but I think that all the security pop ups will jump.